# Do I need redux-promise in this case?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I am testing this api request inside my react-redux application:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
window.$ = $;

const API_KEY = '<api-key>';
const ROOT_URL = `https://api.behance.net/v2/users?client_id=${API_KEY}`;

export const FETCH_USER = 'FETCH_USER';

export function fetchUser(users) {
  const request = $.ajax({
    url: `${ROOT_URL}&q=${users}`,
    type: 'get',
    data: { users: {} },
    dataType: 'jsonp'
  })
    .done(response => {
      console.log('Request:', request);
    })
    .fail(error => {
      console.log('Ajax request fails');
      console.log(error);
    });

  return {
    type: FETCH_USER,
    payload: request
  };
}
```

However, in the Chrome console for `Request:` I am getting an object with `readyState` instead of a `Promise`, do I even need to have the package `redux-promise` at this point?

Answer (score 0):

I see what you are trying to do, but I don't think is a good idea to send a promise to a reducer instead I will recommend you to use the middleware redux-thunk.
I will rewrite your action this way

```
export const fetchUser= ()=>(dispatch,getState)=>{
    let params={
        method:'get',
        body:{ users: {} },

    }
    fetch( `${ROOT_URL}&q=${users}`, params).then
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((response) =>{ 
        dispatch({
            type:Const.ON_RESPONSE_OK,
            payload:response
        })
    })
      .catch(error => {
        dispatch({
            type:Const.ON_RESPONSE_ERROR,
            payload:Error
        })
      });
  }
```

and rewrite the reducer to handle the payloads

Comment: With your solution, I would get told by JavaScript interpreter that Actions must be a plain object.

Comment: You mean a function?

Comment: Using middleware thunk allows creating action generators which return functions instead of actions. In your case you miss returning dispatchers. Check the example asnyc at redux.js.org see https://redux.js.org/advanced/asyncactions

Comment: Is not this code returning a function  fetchUser= ()=>(dispatch,getState)=>{} ?